# Adding ServiceReference in WCF using .map file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to add a WebServieReference in my WCF project. But i am not able to add using the normal way.

I have seen a demo when the reference is added using a `.map` file. I saw a Authentication.map in the ServieReference folder. How can i add a similar reference,

The error i am getting while adding by normal way is,

> server name not resovolved

I gave the reference path as `http://IPADDRESS/SERVICENAME/Authentication.svc?wsdl`, but there is something in the wsdl file, may be a schema file which has a path like `http://SERVERNAME/SERVICENAME/SCHEMAFILENAME.xsd`.

The `SERVERNAME` is making the problem, can anyone help me in this.

Comment: perhaps try adding the ServerName to you C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\Hosts file to temporarily resolve the servername to your ip and let you add the reference?

Comment: thanks @Maverik ,your tip worked. Please submit as answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment above:

perhaps try adding the ServerName to your `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\Hosts` file to temporarily resolve the ServerName to your IP and let you add the reference?